# Algebraic K-theory of schemes and cohomology

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, kt.k-theory-and-homology

Are there examples of:

1. two smooth projective schemes over a field having homotopy equivalent algebraic K-theory spectra and having different rational Voevodsky motives;
2. two smooth projective schemes over a field having the same integral Voevodsky motives and having non-homotopy equivalent algebraic K-theory spectra?

Also, if we take the field to be algebraically closed, is there a Weil cohomology theory whose values (as graded vector spaces) are determined by algebraic K-theory?

Comment: One idea is that dual abelian varieties have equivalent derived categories by Fourier Mukai hence equivalent algebraic $K$ theories, but should have dual motives.  Unfortunately I'm not knowledgeable enough to confirm that this works.

Comment: @PhilTosteson I am also not knowledgeable enough; I think Orlov says they should have rationally equivalent motives (so looks like it does not fly, but maybe I am just being an idiot).